# How to get an attribute value from XDocument when the required XElement name is not known until runtime?

Tags: c#, svg, xamarin.forms, linq-to-xml

I am working with SVG files in Xamarin.Forms.  These files will be very simple, containing a single shape where this shape will typically be a `polyline`.  However, there are edge cases where there could be one of several other point-based shapes.  When parsing these files I am trying to grab the value of a specific attribute on the shape element.

Here's an example of what I expect to be parsing:

```
<svg width="1200" height="800" version="1.1" bordercolor="#666666" borderopacity="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <polyline stroke="#004976" fill="transparent" stroke-width="5" points="479,91 ..." />
</svg>
```

So in this most common case I am trying to get the value of the `points` attribute for a `polyline`.  I'm sure this will be a simple LINQ-to-XML function but I'm missing it.  Here's what I have tried so far:

```
public static Point[] GetPointsFromSVG(XDocument svg)
{
    XElement shape = svg.Descendants().First();
    string pointsValue = shape.Attribute("points").Value;

    var points = pointsValue.Split(' ').Select(x => x.Split(','))
                            .Select(y => new Point(int.Parse(y[0]), int.Parse(y[1])))
                            .ToArray();

    return points;
}
```

I have tried several version of this, but in each case `shape` is `null` even though the `XDocument` object is valid and properly formatted. Also note that I'm not married to this approach, I just need something that works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are expecting exactly 1 "points" attribute then you can just search all descendants for that name:

```
var xmlString = @"<svg width=""1200"" height=""800"" version=""1.1"" bordercolor=""#666666"" borderopacity=""1.0"" xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"">
    <polyline stroke=""#004976"" fill=""transparent"" stroke-width=""5"" points=""479,91 ..."" />
</svg>";

var pointsValue = XDocument.Parse(xmlString)
    .Descendants()
    .Attributes("points")
    .Single()
    .Value;
```

Where `Single()` will throw an exception if there's zero or more than one element in the collection. Or you can remove `.Single()` and `foreach` through all the `.Descendants().Attributes("points")` results.

Answer (score 1):

You're just missing one thing - when you do `svg.Descendants().First()`, it's giving you the first descendant of the document, which is the `svg` element.

Instead, do `svg.Root.Descendants().First()`, or even just `svg.Root.FirstNode as XElement`.

```
string svgString = @"<svg width='1200' height='800' version='1.1' bordercolor='#666666' borderopacity='1.0' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>
    <polyline stroke='#004976' fill='transparent' stroke-width='5' points='479,91 ...' />
</svg>";
var svg = XDocument.Parse(svgString);
XElement shape = svg?.Root?.FirstNode as XElement;

if (shape == null) return null;

string pointsValue = shape.Attribute("points").Value;

var points = pointsValue.Split(' ').Select(x => x.Split(','))
                        .Select(y => new Point(int.Parse(y[0]), int.Parse(y[1])))
                        .ToArray();


Console.ReadKey();
```

Just note that this will not quite work becauase of the "..." in the SVG attribute, which will cause an exception....  Also note that your values could very well end up being decimals/doubles/floats, not ints (e.g. `points='479.994,91.2223 ....'`

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll give this a try! Also thanks for pointing out the `int.Parse` issue, I completely overlooked that.  The `...` is just my way of truncating the list of points.

Comment: Yes, I get that about the `...`, just realize that there are valid non-int values - but no problem.  If this helped, consider upvoting/marking it as the correct answer.